# All pictures has same amount of facebook likes in prettyPhoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, prettyphoto

I'm using [jquery.prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) for displaying photo-albums on my site. I activated the `social_tools` to display twitter and facebook widgets below every photo.

The problem is that if someone likes a photo, all the other photos get a like to, so every photo had 234 likes.

Is this because my `location.href` isn't changing when another picture is showing?

The code to activate my album is:

```
$.fn.prettyPhoto({ 
  slideShow: 3000,
  social_tools: ''
    +'<div class="pp_social">'
      +'<div class="twitter">'
        +'<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a>'
        +'<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>'
      +'</div>'
    +'<div class="facebook">'
      +'<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=nl_NL&href='+location.href+'&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>'
    +'</div>'
  +'</div>'
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a placeholder (or something like that) for the image `id` of image `src`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the jquery.prettyPhoto plugin to fix the problem.

In the section where the facebook links are being replaced I added an extra placeholder:

```
// Rebuild Facebook Like Button with updated href
if(settings.social_tools){
  facebook_like_link = settings.social_tools.replace('{location_href}', encodeURIComponent(location.href)).replace('{image_src}',encodeURIComponent(location.protocol+'//'+location.host+pp_images[set_position])); 
  $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_social').html(facebook_like_link);
}
```

The extra placeholder is `{image_src}` and is is being replaced by the image location.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time ago, albeit not using jquery.prettyPhoto. I had a series of objects, with each a separate webpage. And similarly to you, when someone liked one of the objects, everyone of them got a like.

The issue was that the "like" was linked to the same address and thus considered the same. Once we made sure that they were linked to a different address each, it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just did:

```
// Rebuild Facebook Like Button with updated href
if(settings.social_tools){
  facebook_like_link = settings.social_tools.replace('{location_href}', pp_images[set_position]);
  $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_social').html(facebook_like_link);
}
```

and it worked!

the image url was passed to the FB like href. Now FB understands it is a different url to like.