# prettyPhoto lightbox social tools: all images have the same number of Facebook likes

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, lightbox, prettyphoto

**Background:** I have a site using a prettyPhoto lightbox to display photos. I've enabled social tools to display the 'tweet' and Facebook 'like' buttons on the lightbox, in hope to enable the ability to 'like' *only* the current photo being displayed to the one viewing it.

**Problem:** The Facebook 'like' button actually results in all photos in the same gallery being liked: all photos display the same number of likes in the lightbox; and on Facebook, the user's 'like' in their news feed or recent activity links to the gallery page rather than the actual photo that was liked.

**What I've tried:** I have tried editing the jquery.prettyPhoto.js file to add in the placeholder found in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11796964/2205165

I have also tried replacing 'location_href' with '{path}' to see if that used the photo's full path/URL, but it did not, or didn't appear to do so.

I've tried the above with 'deeplinking' enabled and disabled, with no avail.

**Help:** If anyone has a solution to enable Facebook liking and Twitter tweeting of individual photos from the prettyPhoto lightbox, I'm all ears. Even if it's to the degree of photos displaying the correct number of likes, rather than all having the same number: I'm not too fussed at this stage about linking back to the individual photo: linking back to the main gallery page will suffice for that.

Thank you!

Comment: If you need likes for individual photos, you need to make sure that href for like is pointing to the actual photo (for example ...gallery.php?photoId=16), and that the page in href also has proper meta tags for facebook (using same example, your gallery.php?photoId=16 must contain meta tags for exactly that picture)

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to pull the full image path into the href? I'm guessing the area I need to be looking at is 

// Rebuild Facebook Like Button with updated href
   if(settings.social_tools){
    facebook_like_link = settings.social_tools.replace('{location_href}', encodeURIComponent(location.href));  
 $pp_pic_holder.find('.pp_social').html(facebook_like_link);
   }

Comment: Well, it all depends on your solution. Images are stored somewhere, right? You should know the bath to them, or at least be able to parse href attribute of photos in your gallery with js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever comes up on this again, This solution worked for me and it shares the image directly.

*This is for images only, but there's no reason it wont work for the rest of the cases in PrettyPhoto.*

In your PrettyPhoto parameters in prettyPhoto.js, switch out the facebook iframe to look like this with whatever params you want, all that matters here is that "{path}" is in the href spot of the iframe src:

`<iframe id="fbiframe" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href={path}&amp;width&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21&amp;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:26px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>'`

Then around line 274 in the prettyPhoto.js file you should see this line:

```
$pp_pic_holder.find('#pp_full_res')[0].innerHTML = settings.image_markup.replace(/{path}/g, pp_images[set_position]);
```

Add another line just like it and replace the href for the src like below, again with whatever params you want, the point is that the href is replaces with the image location variable:

```
$('#fbiframe').attr('src', "//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href="+pp_images[set_position]+"&amp;width&amp;layout=button&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=26");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think we're getting somewhere! I didn't quite understand the second part - adding another line and replacing the href for the src, as I couldn't find a href to replace; I simply copied and pasted your line in. Was this correct to do? Now I just need to figure out how to show the number of likes/re-style the lightbox to display FB users' display pictures correctly, without them disappearing over the edges!

Comment: It's also worth noting that when pressing 'like' on a photo displayed in the lightbox, a tiny "add a comment" box appears with no submit-type button, though pressing return on the keyboard submits the like to Facebook. Also, when returning to the photo in the lightbox and hovering over the like button, it still says like rather than unlike, although a cross does appear to denote the action of unliking the photo! I understand these are somewhat unrelated problems however. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Sorry I seemed to have typed that in a hurry after rereading it. By add another line, I meant copy my second line and add it after the first line i posted. You don't want to replace the line because it's doing alot more than just messing with the share button. Also, the comment button is there, you just have to make sure the width of the like button is long enough for it to show, it will hide it if you dont add enough width. I also recommend doing share instead of like because likes basically do nothing these days on fb. They won't even show up on a timeline. GL with this.