# prettyPhoto social tools do not share lightbox deep-link

Tags: javascript, facebook-like, lightbox, prettyphoto, deep-linking

In an attempt to resolve my related prettyPhoto problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148850/prettyphoto-lightbox-social-tools-all-images-have-the-same-number-of-facebook-l), I tried re-enabling deep-linking in hope that its social tools, Twitter and Facebook, would pick up the deep-linked URL and tweet/like/share that instead of the gallery page, but it didn't.

Also, when loading a deep-linked URL such as [this](http://guntrip.org.uk/portfolio-item/nature/#lightbox%5Bauto_group1%5D/2/) in a new tab/window/browser/session, the prettyPhoto lightbox fails to load the corresponding image referenced in the deeplink, but instead loads the page as though the deep-link wasn't there.

I'm not sure if the deep-link sharing issue is due to a problem with the hastag function: `function setHashtag()`in jquery.prettyPhoto.js?

Any guidance on fixing this deep-linking issue will be much appreciated :-)

Cheers!

Comment: any luck with this issue? It appears that this functionality of the plugin has been abandoned somewhat. On the demos from prettyPhoto demo site the like button is greyed out, a { appears where share should be, and on the youtube link where like is working, it only likes the whole page and not the video itself. Do you know of a lightbox that is able to handle fb like and share for the specific image and also for youtube videos?

Comment: I returned to this case late last year with, unfortunately, no resolve :-( the update to the theme I was using on WP didn't help either, as, if I recall correctly, prettyPhoto's files were updated and changed/reverted some of the functionality. I tried recommended solutions I had previously stumbled across and that had been suggested with no luck I'm afraid. I haven't looked for an alternative light box or theme that makes use of one. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

You need to find in your theme some things that need changing (In fact it may be found in file avia.js in your case on line 466)

---1) ,social_tools:'',

---2) ,deeplinking=false,

You need to change to

,deeplinking=true,

and also add 2 elements (iframe_markup, inline_markup), and change social_tools as shown below:

So your new line 466 would look like

```
elements.prettyPhoto({
    social_tools:'<div class="pp_social"><div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div><div class="facebook"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href='+location.href+'&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div></div>',
    slideshow: 5000,
    deeplinking: true,
    overlay_gallery:false,
    default_width: ww,
    iframe_markup: '<iframe src ="{path}" width="{width}" height="{height}" frameborder="no"></iframe>',
    inline_markup: '<div class="pp_inline">{content}</div>',
    default_height: wh
});
```

That's twitter and facebook. Just add what else you want in same format you see above. Nick.

Reference: http://www.kriesi.at/support/topic/single-image-share

Comment: Thanks Nick. However, my line 466 in avia.js is "content: '.toggle_wrap'"; part of the 'defaults' var definition. I do have an "elements.prettyPhoto" line on line 658 though: the line displays "elements.prettyPhoto({ 'slideshow': 5000, 'deeplinking': true });" I tried modifying it to what you recommend but unfortunately it didn't help matters :-(

Comment: Hi there. Over at the page linked at the end of this comment, replacing {location_href} with {path} in the prettyPhoto.js file enables Facebook likes per photo, as opposed to the contaiing gallery. Could this possibly shed some light on this particular case? Cheers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17148850/prettyphoto-lightbox-social-tools-all-images-have-the-same-number-of-facebook-l